# Repeating subtotals in MS Access Report

Tags: ms-access, report, ms-access-2003

The question seems to be quite simple, but I am not being able to solve it.

I have a MS Access 2003 report that exports something like this:

```
Europe
Spain      2 3 4
England    2 2 4
France     1 2 3

Europe Total 5 7 11
```

---

```
Asia
China      3 2 1
Japan      1 2 3

Asia Total 4 4 4
```

And in a final page

```
Grand Total 9 11 15
```

Do you know if there is a way I can repeat the subtotals (e.g. for Europe Total and Asia total, in the final page? Like for example adding an additional footer or something like that?

I would like the output of the last page to be

```
Europe Total 5 7 11

Asia Total   4 4 4 

Grand Total  9 11 15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only really dynamic way I see for this, is to create a separate report calculating the Totals per region (let's call it TotalsPerRegion), and embed that report (as a subreport) in the footer of the main report, setting the subreport's CanGrow and CanShrink properties to True.
This way it will adjust to any number of regions you have.
Hope I am clear...